# react-router show different when component is wraped

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new react user, when i see react-router docs, I confused.
let me show,
first, the docs url: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config
I simplify like this

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Sandwiches
  },
  {
    path: "/tacos",
    component: Tacos
  }
];

export default function RouteConfigExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">/</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/tacos">tacos</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route, i) => (
            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
function RouteWithSubRoutes(route) {
  return (
    <Route
      exact
      path={route.path}
      component={route.component}
    />
  );
}

function Sandwiches() {
  return <h2>/</h2>;
}

function Tacos() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Tacos</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

now, when i click / show /, but click Tacos show nothing.
what expect, click / show /, and click Tacos show Tacos.
**I resolve by these**

```js
// first, do not use component wrap

export default function RouteConfigExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">/</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/tacos">tacos</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route, i) => (
            <Route
              key={i}
              exact
              path={route.path}
              component={route.component}/>
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```js
// second, do not use Switch
export default function RouteConfigExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">/</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/tacos">tacos</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        {routes.map((route, i) => (
            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**It bothered me for a long time, now I'm dying to know why, Please tell me in detail, and thanks so much...**
**In addition, My English is not pretty, understanding...**

Comment: if you wanna see demo,  [react-router-docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config), and copy the code I showed you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Switch` components only valid children are `Route` and `Redirect`, so even though another react component renders a `Route` it won't work quite in the same way.

[Switch children](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node)

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.
>   Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

**Edit**

While wrapped `Route` components *can* still render, *as "grand-children" descendants*, it appears that route props are only applied at the root `Switch` level.

In the following `Switch`, even though `RouteWithSubRoutes` specifies the `exact` prop, `RouteWithSubRoutes` in the react DOM *does not*, so only the first element is returned (coincidentally the home "/" route).

```
<Switch>
  {routes.map(route => (
    <RouteWithSubRoutes key={route.path} {...route} />
  ))}
</Switch>
```

This following `Switch` is identical to the above except for specifying `exact` prop, and this works as expected.

```
<Switch>
  {routes.map(route => (
    <RouteWithSubRoutes key={route.path} exact {...route} />
  ))}
</Switch>
```

**/Edit**

It sounds like you have a two-part question, why both resolutions work.

The first attempt at fixing by rendering a `Route` directly succeeds by specifying the `exact` prop on all routes within the `Switch`, which only matches and renders *the first* matching `Route` or `Redirect`. When the path is *exactly* "/" then that component renders, and when it is *exactly* "/tacos" then that component renders.

The second attempt you render all the routes just right in the `Router`, which matches and renders *all* matching routes, but since you specify, again, the `exact` prop, it matches a single route and works.

**Demo**

[image: Edit react-router-dom Switch vs No Switch]

Comment: Switch components only valid children are Route and Redirect? I might know...    


but I'm confused，in my simplified example,   
why packaged `Route` different from  unpackaged `Route`, could you please explain it in detail, thanks a lot

Comment: @liukun Added an "edit" section to explain hopefully your follow-on question. I also updated the code sandbox with more demos.

Comment: I saw...That's very kind of you. but I have other questions. first, why use reverse  make sense, that put path '/'  to the bottom is effected. second, I want to wrap a Multilevel menu, How to recursively encapsulate Route like Background management system side menu. It is important for me if you show me demo.

Comment: And how to jump to a page without refreshing? like vue.js?
use latest react API

Comment: Using hashHistory? but I am not see this detail... the export?

Comment: @liukun `Switch` renders first route that matches, so without the `exact` prop all routes match "/". If you specify more specific routes before then "/" can only match if all routes before it do not match. Nested routes(sub-routes) can appear anywhere within a Router so it's difficult to answer without seeing what you've tried as anything is possible really. If you have further issues then it would likely be more beneficial to open new questions versus asking them here as you'll certainly get more eyes on it that way.